# Change dimension of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame called "df" (with some NA values inside)

```
dim(df)
[1] 2174  420
```

I would like to change the dimension of it into 32610 rows and 28 columns (by row), for example:

```
 #df=

  a b c d e f g ...
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...    
2 .........   
3 .........    
4 .........    
5 .........    
6 .........    
...........
```

Into:

```
#new.df=

  r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 ...                                                   ... r28
1 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28   
2 29 30 ...   
3 .........    
4 .........    
5 .........    
6 .........    
...........
```

Therefore, new dimension:

```
dim(new.df)
[1] 32610  28
```

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Those numbers seem quite unrelated to each other (2174*420 =/= 32610*428). How about `m = matrix(, 32610, 428); m[] <- df`

Comment: I think it would be `matrix(unlist(t(df)), byrow=T, 32610, 28)` to apply it by row and keep the correct frame.

Comment: I have tried, unfortunately it doesn't work properly

Comment: It is very easy to make a simple example to understand the dynamics involved. Please take the time to make a simple example as I did. Be sure to include the output desired.

Answer (score 6):

To reformat the layout of the data by row we can create an array from the unlisted elements of the original `data.frame`:

```
matrix(unlist(t(df)), byrow=T, 32610, 28)
```

**Reproducible Example**

There is no reason to not have a reproducible example in your question. It is very easy to simplify the problem to understand the underlying solution:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:12,3, byrow=T))
df
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
3  9 10 11 12

matrix(unlist(t(df)), byrow=T, 6, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
[5,]    9   10
[6,]   11   12
```